# bootstrap class="carousel-control left" shadow effect not working

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using bootstrap slider.
the right icon (next) is working fine but the left icon (prev) is not getting the left shadow effect when mouse is over (on the left side).

a link to my project:
http://www.soulbounds.com/ben/ClassicY/index.html

it seems like the `left` class is not working

(I'm using the latest bootstrap version)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quit simple, you did define 2 links with data-slide="prev".

```
<a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">...</a>
<a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">...</a>
<a class="carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"></a>
```

The second is getting the hover without the style for a shadow.

The shadow is defined for the class .left.

Comment: No problem we all miss sometimes the forest for the trees. Could you please mark the question as resolved. So it disapear from the unresolved stack.